# Passing multiple variables by using "FlowSession.send" method

Tags: corda

imaging we have two classes, the **Payer Class** and the **Receiver Class**.
is it possible to pass/ send more than one variable by using the method: 
`FlowSession.send()` ?

When trying e.g. the following

```
sessionWithRecipient.send(Variable1)
sessionWithRecipient.send(Variable2)
```

it seems that only the first variable will be send to the recipient class.

At the responder flow, I use the command shown below to receive the variable and unwrap it:

```
val variable1 = initiatorSession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it }
val variable2 = initiatorSession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it }
```

Could you please help me with a solution to send and receive multiple variables here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending it twice. Just create a wrapper object with all the desired member variables. Then Whitelist this Wrapper object. This way you'll only have to send it once. I find it cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine, printing `Sum is 3.` to the console:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        counterpartySession.send(1)
        counterpartySession.send(2)
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val int1 = counterpartySession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it }
        val int2 = counterpartySession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it }
        logger.info("Sum is ${int1 + int2}.")
    }
}
```